# Some options(table definition,show table data,etc) were lost in Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I just followed the http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-a-new-field tutorial, and exercise in **Visual Studio 2013**. When I finished migrating the database, I opened the database file, and connected into **Server Explorer**. When I right click the table of database, I just find *copy, refresh, property*, but other options(*table definition,show table data,etc*) were lost. How can I see the table data and definition in the Visual Studio?